# Programmatically created web service fails on client service call

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, ssl

I made a console application project to host a web service programmatically, but when I try to create a client proxy to my web service and call a method on it, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://localhost:8000/FileRetrievalPoC. This could be due to the fact
>   that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS
>   in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the
>   security binding between the client and the server.

Its inner exception:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.

Its inner exception:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Its inner exception:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

**Program.cs**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var address = "https://localhost:8000/FileRetrievalPoC";
        Console.WriteLine("Starting a service at {0}...", address);
        FileRetrievalService.Start(address, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "localhost");
        Console.WriteLine("Service started.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to create a new proxy client and call the Get method.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press Escape to end the application.");
        while (true)
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                var proxy = FileRetrievalService.Connect(address, "localhost", "exampleUsername", "examplePassword", StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "localhost");
                proxy.Get(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Document.txt");
                ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                break;
        }
        FileRetrievalService.Stop();
    }
}
```

**IFileRetrieval.cs**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileRetrieval
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Get(string path);
    [OperationContract]
    void Set(string path, string contents);
}
```

**FileRetrievalService.cs**:

```
class FileRetrievalService : IFileRetrieval
{

    private static BasicHttpsBinding _binding = new BasicHttpsBinding()
    {
        Name = "FileRetrievalPoC",
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact,
        Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity()
        {
            Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity()
            {
                AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15,
                ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
            },
            Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
            Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
            {
                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows
            }
        },
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    };
    private static ChannelFactory<IFileRetrieval> _channelFactory;
    private static ServiceHost _host;

    public static void Start(string address, StoreLocation location, StoreName name, string subject)
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileRetrievalService));
        _host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(location, name, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject);
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFileRetrieval), _binding, address);
        _host.Open();
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        if (_host != null)
            _host.Close();
        if (_channelFactory != null)
            _channelFactory.Close();
    }

    public static IFileRetrieval Connect(string address, string domain, string username, string password, StoreLocation location, StoreName name, string subject)
    {
        if (_channelFactory == null)
            _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFileRetrieval>(_binding, address);
        _channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(location, name, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject);
        _channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        _channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
        _channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        return _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public string Get(string path)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Set(string path, string contents)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Its all done programmatically, and I've looked on Stack Overflow but couldn't find a good reason why this is happening. Does anyone know what the problem is? This source code, you can add to a new console application and run it to try it out on your local machine and see it happen for yourself. Is it the SSL certificate? If so, how can I get more verbosity for the error reason here? Its not a very helpful exception.

**Edit**: I think I may have missed a step here, [such as using `netsh` to bind a certificate to my machine's port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that [I did not use `netsh` to bind the certificate to my machine's port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx). Open up an administrative command prompt and call:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 appid=<A randomly generated GUID for your application> certhash=<Your localhost certificate's thumbprint from the default MY store, which is under Local Machine -> Personal, which you can get from the MMC Certificates snap-in>
```

The next step is to make sure its under Trusted People on the client side. At least, for me this is the case since I am using a self-signed certificate that I generated for testing purposes for `localhost`. So for example, if you get a certificate from Comodo or Verisign or some other CA, your certificate may not need this at all since the root CA will be trusted, usually, by default in Windows, since the root CA public certificate for these is shipped out of the box inside of the Trusted Root Certification Authorities section of the Certificates MMC snap-in.

Then, all you need to do, is make sure that your machine credentials are correct. I am using Windows authentication so it tries to assert that my credentials are valid (these are specified in my code on the call to the Connect method).

As I get older, I find I tend to answer my own questions more and more often...

**Edit**: You only need to use the Trusted People store for all of this. If you do want to do this, then use `StoreName.TrustedPeople` in my code above and in your `netsh` command, specify `certstorename=TrustedPeople`, otherwise it defaults to `MY`, which is the `Personal` store in the Certificates MMC snap-in.

Also, to delete an SSL certificate that has been bound, use `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000`

Also, my code doesn't need the client certificate to be set in order to function, so that can be removed from the `Connect` method. Also needs some more tightening up if any of you plan to use it in production.